# Trouble completing the Trailhead Challenge

Tags: trailhead

I enabled namespace prefix in my developer edition which is causing an issue in completing the maintenance exam. I know that we cannot delete the namespace prefix.
Let me know other alternatives to trailhead challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Trailhead Playground. You can create as many as you'd like to complete different challenges. Doing so is usually required from time to time because of missing features, incompatible triggers, etc. You can link up to 10 orgs at once. Regardless of which org you use, you'll get the badges/points/etc for the main login for your trailhead account.

Comment: Can I use the Trailhead Playgroup for Maintenance Exam as well. ?

Comment: @indrasenneelam I haven't taken any such exams, so I don't know. You should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Asked a seperate question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257356/trailhead-playground-for-certification-maintenance-exams