# Trailhead Playground for Certification Maintenance Exams

Tags: trailhead

Can I use Trailhead Playground to complete Certification Maintenance Exam?. I couldn't able to complete the Maintenance Exams with my developer edition due to Namespace Prefix.

Comment: Should be possible to use trailhead playground if that has a namespace prefix, otherwise registering a namespace prefix for dev org is not difficult, its needed anyway in case you would want to learn and enable Lightning components.

Comment: @Raul - Today I cannot complete the maintenance exam in my developer edition because of Namespace prefix.  My question is , Can I use Trailhead Playgroup to complete the maintenance exam ?

Comment: `Can I use Trailhead Playgroup to complete the maintenance exam?` - have you tried it before asking?

Comment: @indrasenneelam The short answer is Yes. You can use any supported org as long as you are able to complete the challenge. Certificate Maintenance are not dependent on Orgs but completion of modules/trails for that matter.

Comment: Raul, JayantDas - Thank You for you response.  Since it is Maintenance Exam , My intention is to check with you before I attempt. I'll work on that and let you know.

Comment: Maintenance exams are free on trailhead and more emphasis of trailhead is to help (force) you learn; not just pass.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use Trailhead Playground to complete Certification Maintenance Exam?

Yes. You can use any supported Org to complete your maintenance exam. The requirement for completing a maintenance exam is to complete a badge on Trailhead. If the module requires you to verify a step in an Org, you can use any Trailhead Playground for that purpose, it is not dependent on your Dev Org at all.

You can find more about the maintenance exam [here on trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=FAQ-Changes-to-Certification-Maintenance).